# VSTS - Can I get different features to show different bugs?

Tags: azure-devops

Afternoon,

I was looking for some help in relation to VSTS.

Is there any way to have a dashboard widget that shows bugs but only shows them for certain features. (Please see picture 1]

We are looking to see.

FRD001 bugs - New and closed 
FRD002 bugs - New and closed 
etc etc

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYQMX.png)

Comment: There is no picture. Please check.

Comment: Hi @smilyface thanks, I have updated it.

Comment: @JSimpson I added a new work around to show the bugs in list (as the work around 1 in my answer), you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since get bugs based on different feature is actually query by **Tree of work items**, while charting in dashboard is not support the tree queries.

But there are two work around for your situation:

#### Work around 1: Add a query results widget in your dashboard

If it’s also ok for you to show the bugs based on different features as below list, you can add a query results widget in your dashboard. Detail steps as below:

[image]

1. Add a new query as below to list bugs based on different features.

   [image]
2. Drag the query you added in step1 under the shared queries (As below example drag the New Query 1 under Current Sprint).

   [image]
3. In your dash board, add **Query Results widget and** select the query you added for the widget configuration.
4. Now bugs will be showed based on different features.

#### Work around 2: show bugs for different features separately

If you only want to show the bugs by chart, you should add queries of bugs for different features separately, and then add charts of the bugs in different features to dashboard separately.